# How to put methods definition into a single file and include it in rails application_controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There are a few method definitions in our rails 3.2 application_controller. Those methods are for all controllers. We would like to put those method definitions into a single file `search_stats_actions.rb` and include it in the application_controller. Into which subdir the file `search_stats_actions.rb` would be dropped and how the file should be included in application_controller? We are looking for preferred practice.

The file is in rails engine and not in rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this would be a module that would be put under the `lib` directory.  Make sure that in your `config/application.rb` you've included the `lib` directory in the `config.autoloads_path`.  See [the Rails app configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) for details.

Then, in your `ApplicationController`, you can `include` the module you just created.

```
class ApplicationController
  include <module name>

  ...
end
```

Comment: There is no application.rb under /config for rails engine. Can we create application.rb under rails /config? Or the solution would be different for rails engine. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting.  This is a default file.  See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

Answer (score 1):

Better place this module (say MY_CUSTOM_MODULE) in the "lib" folders that's included in `config.autoloads_path`. You can then include the module in `ApplicationController` as follows

```
class ApplicationController
  include <MY_CUSTOM_MODULE>
  ... excluded for brevity...
end
```